# Is computer network throughput an independent variable?

Tags: random-variable, independence

The central limit theorem assumes independent variables and I want to apply it to study the performances of my network speed (computer networks). What I have a is the throughput measurements of my network per second. I don't know how to classify my variable, do you think it's a independent variable? 
I have a doubt because this measurements can be influenced by other factors like how many people are using the network and with what type of application etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have confused two similar terms:

A variable is dependent or independent depending on the model you are looking at. This has nothing to do with the central limit theorem and everything to do with your model.

What the central limit theorem (at least, in its most common form) requires is that there be independent random variables. A random variable is a variable that is subject to random variations due to chance. Here the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variables) is quite good.

Comment: Exact, I was mainly asking whether my measurements are independent random variables or not. Because a measurement is different from tossing a die.

Comment: Measurements can certainly be independent random variables.